# How can I replace words in a panda data frame with a number?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using python to analyse survey questions.

I have a large panda dataframe of questions (columns) and each question has a different possible answer e.g. 'agree' 'neutral' 'disagree' & there are around 1800 responses.

I want to replace each word with a numerical value e.g. agree = 1, neutral = 2 and disagree = 3.

N.B. the data type is object not string.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: the function [replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html?highlight=replace#pandas.DataFrame.replace) should do the trick

Comment: How could I use to replace multiple different words though? a for loop?

Comment: why do you want to replace with a number? what do you plan to do with it? Should it be exactly 1/2/3?

Comment: It's a multi-choice survey and I only have the answers as phrases. I want to assign each phrase a number for downstream analysis. Some questions have different answer phrases e.g. some have 'yes' or 'no' whilst others have 4-5 answers. I thought about looping through each column (question) and replacing the phrase with a number but there are 100 questions so will take too long

Comment: Sorry, still unclear to me, you should provide a real minimal example (as DataFrame constructor)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something with the dictionary to replace

```
responses = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}

df.replace(responses, regex=True)
```

Comment: why would use use a regex here?

Comment: All of the strings in both lists will be interpreted as regexs otherwise they will match directly.